# How do you make a function for fetching remote pull requests from github with mac os x?

Tags: macos, git, bash, github

How do you make a bash alias for fetching remote pull requests from github?

The following bash call is used to pull pull-requests from github:

```
  git fetch [remote] pull/[number]/head:pr-[number]
```

Every time I manage a merge conflict I use this to get the pr into a local branch, manage the pr locally and push back up to the repository.  However, I constantly find myself looking up this call and manually inserting the [remote] and [number] (where [remote is the name of the remote repo and [number] is the pull request number)

In the never ending attempt to be a better developer, I would like create a alias(?) that could be reduce this call to the following:

```
  gitpr [remote] [number]
```

How do you do this?  Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible with a git alias. However, it could be done by having in your `$PATH` a script called `git-pr`, which could looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: git pr <remote> <id pr>"
  exit -1
fi


git fetch $1 pull/$2/head:pr-$2
```

It's almost what is done with this [script](https://github.com/gturri/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-pull-mr) made for gitorious merge requests.

Comment: I was hoping I could add it to my .bash_profile so it is with my aliases and easier to maintain.